# Seagate Expansion 2 TB Inaccessible

Tags: format, drive

I'm having difficulty getting my Seagate 2 TB Expansion drive going on Ubuntu 18.04. It's not recognized in Nautilus or any of the GUI disk managers. It is visible in terminal using **lsusb**. I've tried some of the options suggested in other threads, e.g.:

1. **sudo apt-get install ntfsprogs**
   Gives me the message: 
   "Package ntfsprogs is not available, but is referred to by another package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source."
2. **sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g** 
   Gives me the message: 
   ntfs-3g is already the newest version (1:2017.3.23-2).
   0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.

I'd like to run the command sudo **ntfsfix /dev/sdbXX** , but the drive is not listed under **df -h**

I'm not sure what to do. Is this NTFS formatted and do I need to format it with FAT? 

Here is the drive listed under **lsusb**. I'm assuming this is the drive because it doesn't appear when disconnected.

 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0c45:6458 Microdia 
**Bus 001 Device 008: ID 0bc2:231a Seagate RSS LLC**
 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 002: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub 

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What happens when you open `gparted`?

Comment: You may be correct; my box has a external drive connected; and shows *Seagate RSS LLC* on my `lsusb` (list usb devices) too (*I've never noticed it before, but I've never looked for it*).  I usually use `lsblk` (list block devices) where it shows as "sdb disk" (sda is my internal hdd, sdb is type disk - yeah!), and "sdb1 part" or partition. It's the 'sdb1' partition I'll mount. To view it's format, I use `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdb` which will tell me the `mount` command to use. If you prefer GUI, `gnome-disks` is probably easier, but I prefer commands :)

Comment: @Kristopher Ives: gparted stalls at 0% installation.
"Unable to install... E: http:// ... is not yet available (Connection failed)"

Other software is installing...

Comment: @gulverc: The drive doesn't appear when using lsblk.

Comment: @YuBuntu That error says you couldn't install the `gparted` package because it's busy installing other software?

Comment: @Kristopher Ives: I rebooted and ran sudo apt-get clean all, then tried again. Still stalling at 0%.
There's a mirror "dead beef" that I'm having difficulty connecting to. May have to change DNS preferences...

Comment: The drive was fubarred. Got a replacement and it works fine.